# How to open new window in "onclick" javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

In my JSP file , I have a code like below ...how do i write a syntax to open the onclick function which s hould open in new window

```
<label>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:launchNewProfileByUmscode();"><s:text  name="create.prospect.lb2"/></a>
          
 </label>
```

Code from JS

```
function launchNewProfileByUmscode() {

$("#modal-new-edu-user").modal('hide');

if(FPL_CID_CHANGES_2011) {
    var  brNo  = BRANCH_NO;
    var  irNo  = FA_NO;
    
    buildCidWidget(brNo,irNo);
}
```

}

Comment: What does the function you provided have to do with opening new windows? If you want to open a new window, just set the URL in the `href` and add `target="_blank"` to the anchor tag. No JavaScript needed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
window.open("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any advanced JS. Your `launchNewProfileByUmscode` function should just be:

```
function launchNewProfileByUmscode() {
    window.open("WEBSITE URL");
}
```

Here's what happens:

```js
function lauchNewProfileByUmscode(){
  window.open("https://google.com");
}
```

```html
<label>
<a href="#" onclick="lauchNewProfileByUmscode()"><s:text  name="create.prospect.lb2"/>Try me</a>
          
 </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you may want to do like this.

```
  <label>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:void(launchNewProfileByUmscode())">
      <s:text name="create.prospect.lb2" />Link.....</a>
  </label>
  <script>
    function launchNewProfileByUmscode() {
      window.open("https://www.google.com")
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.open()` (see [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)).

Example:

```
window.open("http://www.cnn.com/", "CNN_WindowName", windowFeatures)
```